# NServiceBus: How to stop distributor acting as a processing bottleneck (reduces rate 65%)

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

We have an event processing system that will process events sent directly from the source to handler process at 200 eps (events per second). The queues and message sends are transactional. Adding the NSB distributor between the event generator and the handler process reduces this rate from 200 eps to 70 eps. The disk usage and CPU on the distributor box become significantly higher as well.

Seen with commercial build of NServiceBus, version 2.6.0.1505.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour or have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can play with is where MSDTC is located.  You can have your workers use the same MSDTC as the distributor, therefore downgrading the level of the transaction and speeding up commits.  I would recommend if you do this that you cluster MSDTC to protect against failures.

Assuming you are operating on a DB you could shard your databases to work on different sets of data.  You could also move the DB(s) closer to the workers(to the same machine).

I would also check into the settings of your DB provider and MSMQ as there are a few things to tweak there in terms of timeouts and such.  Note that there is a trade off when applying certain settings, but it sounds like you'd prefer the quickest throughput.

There are lots of other system level things to check, I'll assume you've been through all those items(network/disk/RAM/etc).

Comment: Thanks Adam. We are purely in memory at the moment and MSDTC is co-located.I think the problems we are seeing might be resolved with better hard disk I/O. 70 eps on a standard box still feels low though.